# How to retrieve all the table names from a DB schema in snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to retrieve all the names of the tables in a DB in a particular schema but this is working only on information schema and returning null for others. Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tablename(DB VARCHAR,SC VARCHAR)
RETURNS array
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var t = [];
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "SELECT table_name FROM "+ DB +".information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='BASE_TABLE';"});
    var e = stmt.execute();
    
    while(e.next())
    {
       var x = r.getColumnValue('table_name');
       t.push(x);
    }
return t;
$$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

information_schema.TABLES only displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges.

Maybe you are missing some privileges and that's why you don't see your other tables but only the tables from information_schema?

To check that you can use SHOW GRANTS.

More infos: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html
and https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html

Kind regards :-)

Comment: I not only looking for tables in information schema. I want the tables from other schemas too but how do I retrieve table names from those schemas

Comment: information_schema.TABLES is showing you all tables in all databases/schemas in your account (unless you have enough privileges and the tables aren't dropped).
You have the two columns TABLE_CATALOG (for database) and TABLE_SCHEMA (for schema) to filter. As you are using them correctly in your query, my assumption is that you are using a wrong role (which doesnt have privileges on the tables you want to see as a query result)